# React state object's value in axios request is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, axios, react-hooks

I'm using an **axios** get request to load data and save it in a certain object.
After the data's been loaded successfully I do the same request, and I want to use the already loaded data in the request. Meaning:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})

axios.get('...').then(response => {
    if (data) {
        // Do Something
    } else {
        setData(response.data);
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I enter the `if` statement then the object `data` is always an empty object. I need `data` to be the previously returned response's data.

When debugging the issue, before entering the request, the data in `data` is present, but when entering the `.then` it's empty. I'm fairly new to React but if there's a simple example involving the code I wrote here that'd be a tremendous help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Originally your `data` is `{}` which is a truthy value that's why it is going into that `if` statement. Especially for this type of side-effects what you are trying to achieve there is a hook called `useEffect`.

You can trigger a function once `data` is changing as the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('data changed')
}, [data]);
```

Suggested read is [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Based on this also you need to modify how you are setting the `data` state, see my suggestion:

```
axios.get('...').then(response => {
   setData(response.data);
}
```

In this way you are triggering your actions after `data` is being set.

Comment: Problem is that I want to have an indication of whether information was already retrieved before, and use that in my request. I need that because I'm getting a lot of information in a certain time frame, and every few seconds I want only the delta and not the whole information again. Does useEffect still help here?

Comment: @user10000 Maybe you can introduce a flag as `const [hasRetrieved, setHasRetrieved] = useState(false)` and set in the `useEffect` as `setHasRetrieved(true)`. Thus you can check the value of `hasRetrieved` if the data has already arrived in `.then()` with an `if` statement. Is this somethings which helps?

Comment: I wanted to do that, but I need to be able to access `data` in the **axios** request's response. For some odd reason when debugging outside the `.then` the data's there, but upon entering it `data` is empty. Is there a way to pass `data` into the `.then`?

Comment: @user10000 Do you have a codesandbox where the whole code can be checked? Thanks!

Comment: I actually do not, but I've worked around this issue by keeping a `var` that'll hold previous data. I appreciate your help :)